# How to bind (const void*) parameter in Xamarin iOS Binding

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on binding a 3rd party objective-c library for Xamarin.iOS. This library has a couple method signatures that accept a parameter of type `(const void*)`.

Does anybody know what the binding syntax looks like for that? An example of the method is:

```
-(BOOL)sendBytes:(const void *)data length:(NSUInteger)dataLength answer:(const void *)answer length:(NSUInteger)answerLength;
```

I have it bound as

```
[Export("sendBytes:length:answer:length:")]
unsafe bool SendBytes(IntPtr data, nuint dataLength, IntPtr answer, nuint answerLength);
```

but I have no idea if that is correct or not.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine to me, as far as bindings are concerned, the `const void *` is `void *` and since that is "just" a pointer to some arbitrary memory address, `IntPtr` is the way to go. Of course in the Extras.cs you can wrap that `SendBytes` call into nicer overloaded normalized C# `SendBytes` methods that accepts some structured data/object (byte[], NSData, Bitmap, CIImage, etc...) and calls the raw `SendBytes`.

Comment: sure, that makes sense. right now my goal is just getting the first pass of the binding working. IntPtr seemed right since you can always fall back on that for stuff. 

This is the first time i've had to do this much manual editing to a binding library, so that one thew me for a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer via SushiHangover

> Looks fine to me, as far as bindings are concerned, the const void *
>   is void * and since that is "just" a pointer to some arbitrary memory
>   address, IntPtr is the way to go. Of course in the Extras.cs you can
>   wrap that SendBytes call into nicer overloaded normalized C# SendBytes
>   methods that accepts some structured data/object (byte[], NSData,
>   Bitmap, CIImage, etc...) and calls the raw SendBytes